# How to disable mail about a password is required for command uptime

Tags: debian, uptime

I received lots of local mail about security information:

```
** SECURITY information for localhost
Jan 20 13:58:51 : chepseskaf : a password is required ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/chepseskaf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime
```

I cannot find the way to remove this mail sent automatically on debian stretch 9.7(actually more than 795 messages).

How to find what is responsible ?

Monitoring `/var/log/auth.log`: each time I open a terminal, there is also the same information.

Comment: Do you have a user named `chepseskaf`? If yes, find out what he does.

Comment: yes it's me. All the mail are in my mailbox.

Comment: You might need to trace continuously the log and establish some connection when this happens with what you are doing.

Comment: @harrymc each time I open a console a mail is sent. The same information is logged into /var/log/auth.log